# OPEN/EDIT orchard in VS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

Looking at `http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Manually-installing-Orchard-zip-file`

I am attempting to run the project from VS. I have followed what it has suggested under the `Running the Site Using Visual Studio and the Visual Studio Development Server` heading.
But when I downloaded orchard 1.6 and extract the files all I am left with is:

[image]

then clicking on Orchard folder I am left with:
[image]

Where is the src folder? does anyone know how i can resolve this?
I want to be able to edit my project in VS

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Manually-installing-Orchard-zip-file):

> **Running the Site Using Visual Studio and the Visual Studio Development Server**
>
> To run the site in Visual Studio, extract the full source code .zip file to a local folder.

It's not perfectly clear, but it means the Orchard.Source.1.6.zip (under "Other recommended downloads" in the screenshot on that page) rather than Orchard.Web.1.6.zip.

The former contains all the source required to build Orchard yourself, whereas the latter is a precompiled distribution.